# How to open a .lst file and read the data in php?

Tags: php, file

I have a .lst file in a folder, I used the fopen method,

```
fopen($get_directory()/$subid1/submittedfiles.lst,"r");
```

But it throws error,
failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Perhaps your PHP/webserver doesn't have permissions to access that folder, or that file

Comment: It has permission to access that folder.

Comment: `$get_directory()`?! -- is `$get_directory` a variable whose value is a function? Or the function's name is `get_directory` and the `$` in front of the name is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Your filepath seems not the good one

Have you tried sommething like that ?
Are you sure about your file location ?

```php
fopen($get_directory()."/".$subid1."/submittedfiles.lst","r");
```

If it's not working try to display your filpath construction

```php
var_dump($get_directory()."/".$subid1."/submittedfiles.lst");
```